# How select combobox item using Hotkeys?

Tags: wpf

In WPF, I am using a combobox for hold a collection. I need to select each item using Ctrl +numeric key. For example if there are 5 items available in combobox then all these 5 tasks should be accessable when user presses Clt + 1, Clt + 2, Clt + 3, Clt + 4, Clt + 5.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
 private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyboardDevice.GetKeyStates(Key.LeftCtrl) != KeyStates.Down &&
             e.KeyboardDevice.GetKeyStates(Key.RightCtrl) != KeyStates.Down ||
            e.Key <= Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.D9) return;

        var combo = (ComboBox)sender;
        var idToSelect = e.Key - Key.D1;

        if (combo.Items.Count > idToSelect)
            combo.SelectedIndex = idToSelect;
    }
```

I've tested it as handler on combobox so the sender is ComboBox and it requires focus on combo to work but it can be modified to your needs.